# woocommerce shop page Redirect Help

Tags: redirect, woocommerce-offtopic, customization

How can I redirect my wordpress shop page from. www.domain.com/shop to shop.domain.com.

Please help

Also my site has been adding deleted products to my customers orders.

They are not being charged for the deleted orders, but the orders showing up on their receipts is causing alot of confusion.

Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the servers htaccess file. Try this:

```
 # This will redirect a subdomain to another domain
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://shop.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

This should redirect anyone from the www. to the shop. domain.